# Extending a block disables whole output on Magento2 - Product - Reviews

Tags: magento2

I've tried to extend `\Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView`. I've did so by creating a new module, `MS_RealReviews`. Within that I've created `Block/Review.php` and `etc/frontend/di.xml` and a few others. This is my file tree:

[image]

Block/Review.php:

```
<?php
namespace MS\RealReviews\Block;

class Review extends \Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView
{

    public function isRealReview(){
        // Codebla
    }

}
```

etc/frontend/di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> 
    <preference for="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView" type="MS\RealReviews\Block\Review" />
</config>
```

`default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>


        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceContainer name="product.info.details">
                <block class="MS\RealReviews\Block\Review" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data" template="product/view/list.phtml"/>
            </referenceContainer>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceBlock name="product.info.product_additional_data" remove="true" />

    </body>
</page>
```

The `list.phtml` is an unmodified copy of the original file.

When now checking the product page, I do not get any output anymore. I see the form, but once submitted and enabled in the backend, the review is not there.

What am I missing here?

Comment: why this extends `Extending  block ` required?

Comment: Hi Amit, what do you mean?

Comment: why  u have extending this block class!!!

Comment: I extend `Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView` because I want to extend the output of list.phtml on a product page. I understand that you need to extend the block for the template you want to add $this->functions for. I wish to cross-check the user ID to the order database and show an amazon-like "Verified Customer" text beside the nickname, if the customer has bought the item he reviews. Hope this clarifies it a bit

Comment: You might wanna check this question as well, its related directly to it with a little more insight. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166242/how-to-check-if-review-is-from-a-customer-who-has-purchased-the-reviewed-item-in

Comment: Check updated question for more details. @AmitBera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. In the end I got 2 errors to solve.

I my case the cause of the failure was my wrong `referenceContainer` tag instead of `referenceBlock` in `default.xml`. This caused an Exception and rendered the page useless.

And there was a type, also in `default.xml`. I've used the wrong class name. I had that already fixed when edited the Question.